# Less: changing wrapper width on different screens, based on a gutter variable

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid, less

**Wrapper without padding but with smaller % width**

I'm using a smaller wrapper instead of padding or margin for a website. This is becouse our grid system doesn't like paddings and stuff.

I'd like to use a width based on a gutter size.

**My idea, example:**

The total width of the wrapper would be 100%
I'd like 2% space around it so the gutter size is going to be 2%
After that I'll do `width: 100% - (2* guttersize);` - thats's 2% for each side ofcourse

**How to change when screensize is smaller?**

Now I want to change the width when the screensize gets smaller. So when the screen gets smaller I'll do somthing like `width: 100% - (4*guttersize);`

How can I make this work in Less?

I now have this:

```
#responsiveLayout > .set(1200px);
@media (max-width:1200px) and (min-width:768px){
     #responsiveLayout > .set(1200px);
}
@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width:480px) {
    #responsiveLayout > .set(767px);
}
@media (max-width : 479px) {
    #responsiveLayout > .set(479px);
}


#responsiveLayout {
    .set(@availableW) {
        @wrapperW : 100%;
    }
    .set(@availableW) when (@availableW =< 1200){
        @wrapperW : 100% - (@gutter*4);
        @gutterSize: @gutter*4;
        .wrapper{
            width: @wrapperW;
        }
        .menuBar{
            padding: 0 @gutter;
        }
    }
    .set(@availableW) when (@availableW =< 767){
        @wrapperW : 100% - (@gutter*4);
        @gutterSize: @gutter*4;
        .wrapper{
            width: @wrapperW;
        }
        .menuBar{
            padding: 0 @gutter;
        }
    }
    .set(@availableW) when (@availableW =< 479){
        @wrapperW : 100% - (@gutter*6);
        @gutterSize: @gutter*3;
        .wrapper{
            width: @wrapperW;
        }
        header{
            .wrapper{
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works a little bit but the css gets overwritten too many times. I thought about (@availableW =< 799) and (@availableW => 479) but for some reason that also does not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I'd try something like this:

**LESS:**

```
@screenL:~"screen and (min-width: 1024px)";
@screenM:~"screen and (min-width:768px and max-width:1023px)";
@screenS:~"screen and (max-width:767px)";
@gutter:100px;
@media @screenS{
    .wrapper{
        width:@gutter * .98;
    }
}
@media @screenM{
    .wrapper{
        width:@gutter * .95;
    }
}
@media @screenL{
    .wrapper{
        width:@gutter * .92;
    }
}
```

**CSS output:**

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 98px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width:768px and max-width:1023px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 95px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 92px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me! This is kind of what I'm looking for. There's one more thing I'd like to be able to do and what isn't possible that way (I think): I'm having some absolute positioned elements and I want to give them the @gutter as distant from the edge (in the main.less to keep it clean). Is that possible?

Comment: I think you might want to also include a margin property within each media query in the css.  If you say margin:0 auto, it will be 0 along the top and bottom and center itself along the left and right.  Hope that's helpful.  In any case, good practice for Stack Overflow is to mark the answer as helpful and/or correct so other readers are aware.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you're trying to do?  Maybe a graphic?  I'm not sure I understood what you ask in your comment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me out. The main issue is to change a variable inside a mediaquery. And then use it again, outside the mediauery, in my main.less file.

Comment: I'm thinking that's what I addressed in my answer.  So, At the top, I declare the **@gutter** variable, and within the three media queries, that variable's value changes value when I multiplied it by various numbers.  The **@gutter** variable is still available to use elsewhere as well.  Or if you want to use an altered version of it again, declare a new variable, like **@gutterChanged**, and set that value in one of the media queries.  The declared variables are available anywhere throughout your less.  Does that help?

Comment: I just find out I can't use enters here :( I wanted to say a bit more. To be more clear: I have a main.less, resposive-variables.less and variables file. The thing I'd like to be able to do is: set the variables in responsive variables.less for diffrent screen sizes, after that: only type for example `.bxnav{width:@gutterSize}` into my main.less file (which has no mediaqueries). When I have typed that, the value of @guttersize is automaticly set, based on the variables set in the mediaqueries of responsive-variables.less. It's the same story for the wrapper width ofcourse.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't respond to your solution very well. I appreciate the quick response. Thanks! Hmm, I can't type `.wrapper: @gutterSize` without `@media @screenL` around it right? That's kind of what I'd like to be able to do.

Comment: You definitely need the media queries wrapped around the classes in order to change the values based on screen size.  I'm not sure why you need multiple less files.  I realize you can include them in other files (I've never actually done that before, myself), but it seems to me it would be easier for you if you have all of the less in one file.